# How to pass a variable from testscript file to common file in automation

Tags: python

For  iOS automation, I have a re-usable script file called funclib.py.  The file is like :

```
if “iPad in device :
    from iPad_resource import *
else:
    from iPhone_resource import *

def fnCreateaccount(email,password,device):
    wd.find_element_by_name("Create an Account").click()
    wait("Create account”)
     wd.find_element_by_xpath(r.email_field()).send_keys(email)
     wd.find_element_by_xpath(r.password()).send_keys(password)
     wd.find_element_by_name("Create account").click()
    wd.find_element_by_name("Agree & Sign up").click()
    wait("Create Vault")
    if(wd.find_element_by_name(“Created Account").is_displayed()):
        tcResPass(" Account is Created")
    else:
          tcResFail("Error in creating account")
    return(email, password)
```

And I have many Testscript files, For each test script, the device will be different. For example , initial.py is a test script file

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Device = “iPad 2 Retina”

def CreateNewAccountLogin(): 
    email=generateemail(1,12)
        password=get_password(letters,6)
        fnCreateNA(email, password, device)
```

When I run this, I am getting error like :

```
`device is not defined in funclib.`
```

How can I pass the device value to funclib.py ? I can’t import the initial.py to funclib, because like that I have around 20 test script files. So I need to import everyone which doesn’t make sense.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Is that your real file?? You're not going to get anything done capitalizing `if`/`else` and putting typographical quote marks in Python source files.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Device = "iPad 2 Retina"`, you set a local variable in the `initial` module called `Device`. The `funclib` module and the `initial` module have different local variable namespaces. To set a variable on `funclib`, you have to **do so explicitly** by saying `funclib.Device="iPad 2 Retina"`.

Comment: I cant explicitly declare a value for funclib because, It will change the device value according to the test script file. For example, I have 5 test script files ( initial1.py, initial2.py and so on) and each has different device, my funclib.py has to get the device value when that particular testscript is executing. For intsance.py if device is " iPad Mini" - funclib also should be iPad Mini and if instance2.py its "iPhone 6", the funclib also should have same value. @ppperry

Comment: What do you mean? Woudl it work to pass the device as arguments to `funclib`?

Comment: Thats my doubt, how can I pass the current device value to funclib based on the current testscript file ?

Comment: The main part where the funclib has to identify device is  :

if “iPad in device :
    from iPad_resource import *
else:
    from iPhone_resource import *


Based on the device type only I can import the resource file. So Since each test script device is different. I need to pass device value to funclib.py. Please help !!!!!

Comment: @ashokpanicker Modules are cached in `sys.modules`, so if you test both iphones and ipads, your system is already flawed, as only one set of resources is imported